# How to split the 2048 bits BigInteger into words with a fixed number of 64 bits?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a key that contains 2048 bit BigInteger number. I want to break it into words with a fixed number of 64 bits, and then compute the exclusive OR of all those words; can anyone help me to implement this by java?

example:

> Big Number(key):
>   11380312415897726212538720767584623938377542218843650885786488543557849920563944820657401556147072220807050423844611527817088743264179887246035449031879964033048917437051768727745163996083995699396309860629605332639267450328379289961205789359923142431676348109877819086396004913235006262427231898532203764657706261780748597526471127787542155628754978941021278802504747939847153450812209928520258539639347968927907337576400038705453704498741239631581573919339705649004208586949422810873621196157474272177586468236634536851618181572350294408509526514361027546939234421045026063811415872877733865949984217287267027217419
>
> output(parity checksum:) 10249015871569703692

this is my method that implemented but it doesn't work correctly:

```
 /**
     * *
     * Receives a 2048 bits key and applies a word by word XOR to yield a 64 bit
     * integer at the end.
     *
     * @param key 2048 bit integer form part A1 DH Key Exchange Protocol
     * @return A 64 bit integer
     */
    public static BigInteger parityWordChecksum(BigInteger key) {

        LongBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(key.toByteArray()).asLongBuffer();
        long xor = 0;
        while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
            xor ^= buffer.get();
        }
        return BigInteger.valueOf(xor);
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking to solve a problem. "this is my method that must be implemented"-We don't solve problems for others. Show us what you tried.

Comment: @SajalDutta *because asking to solve a problem.* Not a right reason. I think it's too  broad.

Comment: I tried to solve it.i implemented that but it's not true. I edit my question and write my code

Comment: Not sure how your solution behaves when the buffer size is not a multiple of 8 bytes.

Comment: @haraldK keep in mind, that `toByteArray()` returns one byte more if the first bit would otherwise be a 1 to make it a positive number.

Comment: @Henry Sorry, I was wrong about the underflow. :-O The `ByteBuffer.asLongBuffer(...)` seems to handle this fine, `remaining()` will be the multiple of 8. Might cause a bug if you have a negative number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use only `BigInteger`s in your method (instead of long), you can do it like that:

```
public static BigInteger parityWordChecksum(final BigInteger key) {
    BigInteger result = new BigInteger("0");

    BigInteger mask = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        mask = mask.setBit(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i += 64) {
        result = result.xor(key.shiftRight(i).and(mask));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice, +1 However, I suspect this one is quite a bit slower than the OP's method, due to the `BigInteger` calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is mostly correct, however, a Java `long` is *signed*, but your expected  output assumes that it is unsigned. You can easily fix this by replacing the `BigInteger.valueOf` with the appropriate `BigInteger` constructor (and some bit massaging to get a `byte` array from the `long` value), like below:

```
public static BigInteger parityWordChecksum(BigInteger key) {
    LongBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(key.toByteArray()).asLongBuffer();
    long xor = 0;

    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        xor ^= buffer.get();
    }

    ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    result.putLong(xor);

    return new BigInteger(1, result.array()); // Signum 1 for unsigned
}
```

Output:

```
10249015871569703692
```